# WEXITSTATUS command

Tags: linux, operating-system

I'm trying to figure out what the following code does:

```
int main()
    {
    int value = 3;
    if (fork() != 0)
    {
        wait(&value);
    }
    else
    {
        exit(value);
    }
    value = WEXITSTATUS(value);
    value++;
    printf("%d", value);
    return value;
}
```

I know it creates one son proccess, it also tells the father proccess to wait for the son proccess. and orders the son proccess to exit with exit(3).
when I debugged my answer I saw that the command: wait(&value) on line 6 returns 3*256, but I read that its suppose to return the low-order 8 bits of the exit status value from the child process, meaning it can't be above 255. it does not change my output of 4, that is the exit status plus 1, but I'm still interested where and why do I get this 256.
Can someone please explain what am I missing, or not understanding completely?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The source of your confusion is that that you are dealing with operating system services that were poorly designed.,

You need to look at the documentation for the wait () function:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wait.html

What happened is that this function designed-by-accident crams a lot of things into a single return parameter. There are a number of macros that will unpack this return value into its separate components by expanding the bit fields.

The reason you are getting 3*256 rather than 3 is that the function has to make room for the process exit status, which apparently is 0. You're getting the binary value:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 0000 0000
|UNUSED           |
                    |Process 
                     Return 
                     Value  | | Other Stuff |
```